# How would I check if every element in a row within a 2D array is the same in C?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, char, row, col

So for example if I had a 2D array of char seatingChart[5][5] =

```
x x . x x
. x . x x
. . . . .
x x x x .
. . . . .
```

How would I print out that the 3rd and 5th rows are all "."?

I was trying to do it like this

```
for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
                    }
                if (seatingChart[row][0-9] == "."){
                        printf("Row %d is empty",row+1);
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there a quicker way of doing this without writing && multiple times in the if statement? because my actual seating chart has 1000 rows and 1000 columns

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by

1. Set "all elements in this row is `.`" flag.
2. Iterate over the row.
3. When you find an element that is not `.`, clear the flag.
4. After the iteration, check the flag to see the result.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char seatingChart[5][5] = {
        "xx.xx",
        ".x.xx",
        ".....",
        "xxxx.",
        "....."
    };

    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
        int is_all_dot = 1;
        for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
            if (seatingChart[row][col] != '.') {
                is_all_dot = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (is_all_dot) {
            printf("Row %d is empty\n", row + 1);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just check to see if the next element is the same as the current element, and if the whole row passes then you flag the row index as being all the same. If any of the checks fail you can move on to the next row because it invalidates the entire row.

Answer (score 0):

For this I would recommend writing a separate function for checking rows. This both makes the program more readable and you can use early return as part of your algorithm:

```
bool row_empty(size_t row_length, const char row[row_length])
{
  for (size_t n = 0; n < row_length; n++)
    { 
      /*
        As soon as we see a non-empty seat, we know that the
        row is empty
       */
      if (row[n] != '.')
        return false;
    }

  /* We only reach this point if all the seats were empty */
  return true;
}
```

Now, looping through your rows becomes dead simple:

```
for (int row = 0; row < num_rows; row++)
  {
    if (row_empty(row_length, seatingChart[row])
      {
         printf("Row %d is empty",row+1);
      }
  }
```

Some final notes:

I removed the hardcoded value `5` for your benefit.
You have to add `#include <stdbool.h>` to use `bool`, `true` and `false`.
If your compiler doesn't have `stdbool.h` you have to use `int`, `1` and `0`